# Blazor getting error by clicking Login menu on webassembly server project

Tags: authentication, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have create a Blazor WebAssembly with authentication, 
defined the database in json setting file and Update-database by nuget console.
I ran the application it works fine after for customization purpose i have added the identity scaffolding features by clicking Add => new Scaffolding item on my server project, then I select all the customization item/layout for it and provided the modal for it.
After running the app it is still working for the Home page but when I clicked on the Login/Register menu it getting the following error

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered by the page at '/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml': 'Scripts'. To ignore an unrendered section call IgnoreSection("sectionName").
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage.EnsureRenderedBodyOrSections()

System.InvalidOperationException: The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered by the page at '/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml': 'Scripts'. To ignore an unrendered section call IgnoreSection("sectionName").
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage.EnsureRenderedBodyOrSections()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderLayoutAsync(ViewContext context, ViewBufferTextWriter bodyWriter)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|29_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IEndpointRouter router, IUserSession session, IEventService events)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.MutualTlsTokenEndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapWhenMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Comment: i did it but no luck

Comment: Did you solve this @AlamdarKhan? I am facing exactly the same issue, but I'm afraid the selected answer doesn't look good  as it will break all the scripts won't it?
Strangely, I did this same exercise with the pre release code back in Feb (Ish) and it worked fine then. Its obviously a scaffolding issue, but I really don't like it when scaffolding (something thats meant to help) breaks the app..

Comment: Yes, use the code below for each page you are getting error
`<div class="content px-4">
        @RenderBody()
        @{
            @if (IsSectionDefined("Scripts"))
            {
                IgnoreSection("Scripts");
            }


        }
    </div>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eliminating the generated file *Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Shared/_ViewStart.cshtml* solves this issue without changing anything in *_Layout.cshtml*

You will also see that the scaffolder generates *Pages/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml* in , which I eliminated because it was redundant. From the start there is one in *Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml* which is the one I kept.

If you do add the

```
@RenderSection("Scripts", false)
```

Part you will notice that the navbar disappears because the project stops recognizing the existence of the *_LoginPartial.cshtml* even if you do have the original and the generated one.

Comment: Excellent, bárbaro! gracias Carlos, only thing is in my case that file _ViewStart.cshtml was under /Areas/Identity/Pages/ . Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Than means, than on your `_Layout.cshtml` page there is a statement

```
@RenderSection("Scripts")
```

And there is no

```
@section Scripts {
...
}
```

On the page, using `_Layout.cshtml` as a layout page. To prevent such errors, you can change

```
@RenderSection("Scripts")
```

into

```
@RenderSection("Scripts", false)
```

which will make the `Scripts` section not mandatory for pages, using this layout.

Comment: this is default code in _Layout.cshtml
@{
    Layout = "/Areas/Identity/Pages/_Layout.cshtml";
}

html here
@section Scripts {
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)

Comment: Ah, that's exactly the opposite situation. Your child component defines the section Scripts, which is not defined in the parent view. @section Scripts { @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false) implies that a _Layout has a parent view itself and there a Scripts section should be defined. Either put @RenderSection("Scripts") into parent View, or put there @IgnoreSection("Scripts") (I'm not sure that's good idea, because your scripts can vanish from resulting html).

Comment: Or just change @section Scripts { @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false) } into  @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false). I'm almost sure, that you do not use an outer layout over the _Layout.cshtml and that weird code is just a glitch of template creator.

Comment: This is valid, but in my case it also caused the navbar to disappear which is a strong visual contrast. In my answer I covered a way to make it work as expected without this problem.